# Javascript Dynamic GetElementByID

Tags: javascript, dynamic, getelementbyid

I would like to use the same function on two different elements without duplicating my code and changing the id. I'd like to pass the ID as a parameter into my function but it's not working.

```
function getSelected(id){
            var selected = new Array();
            **var selObj = document.getElementById(id);** //The problem is here
            var count = 0;
            for (x=0; x<selObj.options.length; x++){
                if (selObj.options[x].selected){
                    selected[count] = selObj.options.value;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            alert(count)
        }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure that the `id` is string

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Besides showing us the error message (if any), please make sure what is contained in `id`. You can use `console.log` to print it to the browser console. Also, how do you call this function? Please edit your question and add at least these details.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me as if the error is somewhere else, specificially in this line:

```
selected[count] = selObj.options.value;
```

Shouldn't that be:

```
selected[count] = selObj.options[x].value;
```

or (without the need for an extra "count" variable)

```
selected.push( selObj.options[x].value );
```

(Furthermore, you're missing a `var` in front of `x = 0`, thus making x a global variable.)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I actually caught the "selObj.options[x].value" a few minutes after posting. Also I had no idea that I was creating global variables when I didn't use "var". I'm a JS novice, and will be sure not to make that mistake again.

I made those changes, to no avail.

Comment: Are you maybe able to produce a minimal example via http://jsfiddle.net ? Your code looks okay so far.